Should share startup idea or not?
I was just wondering that whenever we get a startup idea should we share it with other people around us and online or not. Because what if they implement your idea before you and then what you can do is just watch someone get advantage from your idea and basic plan to implement it.

You could edit this question to be more specific about issues of protecting those idea with patents. Otherwise it is probably off-topic.

BLANK, no; I have done this, with some inventions & cannot get the startups off the ground. I have had not enough resources almost every single time, some those inventions, then were done before I could get the resources. Remember 90+% of startups crash & burn; you never know what is around the corner. I would never use the outlaw tools of The Internet to do it. Maybe, some exremely sly media done, but be extremely careful.
My every own brother was not using an invention, but high tech (he knows a lot more than me about both Canabis & technology- his job) startup company none less, in Canabis. I tried to wise him up; I know politics better than all that were involved; thanks to Independent & non-Pofit Left political media. Yes, thanks Capitalism Monopolization their business crashed & burn, they had everything going right, except law makers of their state & federal government's okaying, but making it impossible.
